# "List index out of range"/null value for secondary list

Tags: python, list, null

I'm trying to add a new section to my program that searches for bots on our server and deletes them, but I'm running into a show-stopping issue: Whenever the program gets to the second part (what I've added) the output for 'readFirst' is '[]'. When the next couple of lines run I get a "list index out of range" error for obvious reasons.

I have no idea why this is happening, as the readlines variable shouldn't be shared by both parts of the program.

Here is the code:

```
while runTimes >= 0:
#Cycles through .php files
openedProg = glob.glob('*.php')
openedProg = openedProg[currentPhp:currentPhp+1]
progInput = ''.join(openedProg)
if progInput != '':
    theBot = open(progInput,'r')

    #Singles out "$output" on this particular line and closes the process
    readFourthFromBottom = theBot.readlines()
    wholeLine = (readFourthFromBottom[-4])
    output = wholeLine[4:11]

    #Singles out "set_time_limit(0)"
    readFirst = theBot.readlines()
    print(readFirst)
    wholeLine2 = (readFirst[0])
    output2 = wholeLine2[7:24]
    print(output2)

    theBot.close()
if progInput == '':
    currentPhp = -1
```

Comment: So I should switch "readFourthFromBottom = theBot.readlines()" (crappy name preserved for consistency) to "readFourthFromBottom = theBot.all_lines()"?

The problem here is that this wrapper doesn't seem to have that attribute.

Comment: Here we go. Just had to take out the second readlines reference. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You are reading all the lines the first time you do readlines().

The second time you call readlines, it starts at the end of the file, so there's nothing to read.

The `readFirst` variable is worthless, you already have all the lines in the poorly named `readFourthFromBottom` variable.

Comment: Now when I run this on the server "output2 = wholeLine2[6:23]", when called later, says it is "not defined". This does not happen in my sandbox. I have the same version of python installed on both.

Answer (score 0):

`readlines()` reads all the way to the end of the file stream, which means that the cursor is at the end of the file.  Really, the problem here is that `readFourthFromBottom` is an inaccurate variable name.  It should be `all_lines`, because it will contain all the lines from the file in a list.  Then you should just use that instead of trying to re-read the lines in to `readFirst`.

Answer (score 0):

`readlines` will read all lines from the IO object. So any subsequent try to read something from the file will yield EOF and as such the second `readlines` will never return anything else.

You could [seek](http://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.IOBase.seek) to the beginning of the file before using `readlines` again, or even better, just *reuse* the lines you read once. Unless you modify the `readFourthFromBottom` (which is a terrible variable name btw.), which you don’t, there is no reason to read the lines *again*.